# Rails 5 access profile data anywhere in session without querying database each time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5

I've a user profile (with name, logo, about_me) which is created after user creation(using Devise). Profile table uses user_id as Primary key.

Now I want that whenever the user creates/updates a post, while filling in form some details are taken from profile, so profile data or @profile be available in post form as I cannot expose my model in form. 
To set post.myname attribute in create and #update I'm doing this:

```
@myprofile = Profile.find_by_user_id(current_user)
write_attribute(:myname, @myprofile.name)
```

I read from various sources but what's the best solution of the 4 given and if anyone can back with easy code as I do not want to do something extensive? Thanks in advance.

1)Form Hidden fields - Like get the profile data as above in hash in #edit and then pass through form and access fields in #update but that way we will pass each field separately. Can one @myprofile be passed?

2)Session - I feel if profile data is stored in a session and someone updates profile then updated data won't be available in that session.So not sure if it is plausible.

3)Caching - easy way to do that?

4)polymorphic profile---tried it but I didnot get relevant example. I was stuck with what to put as profileable id and type and how to use them in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Profile and User models have a one-to-one relationship with each other, the simplest solution is to remove the Profile model altogether and move its fields into the User model.

Devise already queries the database to obtain the `current_user` object. So, your example would like this:

```
write_attribute(:myname, current_user.name)
```

Which wouldn't hit the database (after Devise has retrieved the `current_user` object).

---

If you're forced to keep the Profile model, in looking at your four scenarios ...

2. You *could* use a session variable. Something like:

   ```
   session[:profile_name] ||= @myprofile.name
   ```

   This would go in a controller action.

   The trick here is that you will want to redefine the each relevant session variable if the profile gets updated. And because you don't have access to the session in the model, you'd be best to perform that action in the controller. So, not pretty, but it could work.
3. You could also use low-level caching, and save the profile relationship on the user. In general, you could have a method like this in your user model:

   ```
   def profile_cached
     Rails.cache.fetch(['Profile', profile.id]) do
       profile
     end
   end
   ```

   Here, too, you will have to know when to expire the cache. The benefit of this approach is that you can put this code in the model, which means you can hook its expiration in a callback.

   Read more about this in [Caching with Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html).

I would avoid hidden fields and I'm not sure how a polymorphic relationship would solve you not hitting the database. So, #2 and #3 are options, but if you can combine the two models into one, that should simplify it.

Comment: Thx, @seancdavis.I first decided to include all profile details in user but user table got complicated and I didnot wish to disturb Devise table.Regarding option 2 in your reply- I've 2 questions: Firstly, If I update profile how to ensure that session will be updated too 'instantly'? Secondly, is this session code included in profilescontroller#create? Mind you session is created as soon as user is signed-up or signed if-in but profile maynot exist in user creation & thus, I cannot put session code in sessionscontroller

Comment: You're unlikely to interfere with Devise with a few simple profile fields. But in any case, I added a bit of detail to my answer to address your two questions.